# How to do Email validation using Regular expression in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, typescript

I have an requirement to validate email and date fields from an Excel file using typescript Angular app.

And I am trying to validate using regular expression but the result returns always false for a correct email address.

Can anyone help me to validate the email and dates?

Below is the code I have written

**Component:**

```
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import {UploadService} from '../services//upload.service';


import { FileUploader ,FileItem,ParsedResponseHeaders,FileLikeObject} from 'ng2-file-upload';

import { SpotCheck } from '../models/SpotCheckFields';  

@Component ({  
    selector: 'my-app',  
    templateUrl:'./excelUpload.html',
    providers:[UploadService]
})  

export class ExcelUploadComponent  { 

    public SpotChecklist: SpotCheck[];
    public project_master:any[];

    uploader:FileUploader;

    constructor(private uploadservice: UploadService ){
        this.SpotChecklist=[];
        this.project_master=[];
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/upload'
            // headers: [{name:'Accept', value:'application/json'}],
            // autoUpload: true,
        });
        this.uploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onErrorItem(item, response, status, headers);
        this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onSuccessItem(item, response, status, headers);

        // retrieve projectmaster details
        this.getProjectMaster("","SELECT PROJECT MASTER");
    }

    onSuccessItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
        //console.log("onSuccessItem " + status, response, item);  
        this.SpotChecklist = JSON.parse(response); //success server response

        var data = this.validateRow(this.SpotChecklist);

        console.log(data);  
    }

    onErrorItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
        let error = JSON.parse(response); //error server response
    }

    validateRow(lst:any[]) : SpotCheck[]
    {
        var i:number;
        for(i=0;i<lst.length ;i++)
        {
            var validation_message:string="";
            var blnErrOccured:boolean=false;

            if(!this.isEmail(lst[i].RESPONSIBLE_PERSON_EMAIL_ID))
            {
                validation_message=validation_message+ "," +"RESPONSIBLE_PERSON_EMAIL_ID is invalid"
                blnErrOccured=true;
            }

            lst[i].VALIDATION_RESULT=validation_message;
        }
        return lst;
    }

    isDate(date:string) {
        // return (new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date") && !isNaN(new Date(date));
    }

    isEmail(search:string):boolean
    {
        var  serchfind:boolean;

        regexp = new RegExp('/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/');

        serchfind = regexp.test(search);

        console.log(serchfind)
        return serchfind
    }

    getProjectMaster(project_code:string,Flag:string):any
    {  
        this.uploadservice.getProjectMaster(project_code,Flag).subscribe(
            response=> {
                this.project_master= response[0];
                return response;
            },
            error=> {
                console.log("ERROR: ",error);
                console.log(error.json()); //gives the object object
            },
            () => {
                console.log("Completed");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have copy the code from the above link it self.

Comment: what's the output of your code. does it validate incorrectly? or not validating at all? any errors in console?

Comment: no error!!! it just returns false for correct email address also

Comment: It's not realistic to use a regex. Use the built-in parsers for URL and Date, passing in the values and see what happens (Nodejs and the browsers get regular updates for these things, so why duplicate concerns generally?). In the case of URLs simply add a protocol before. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966778/965666 This has been asked so many times.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Problem is with the regex format given. Give it without quotes (') like this

```
regexp = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
```

Comment: Yeah.. working... thank you

Comment: Might not work for something other than english. Will post what I use.

Comment: this example returned true. che@ghehxhe

Comment: @AbdullahNurum actually this is true, as like localhost is a valid domain.